# How to increase the size of the root directory in centos 6

Tags: linux, centos6, root

how i can increase the size of the root directory .i face some problem of cache of my sql.
result of command df -h

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_root
                      50G   24G   23G  51%  /
tmpfs                 16G     0   16G   0%  /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             477M   42M  411M 10%  /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_host-lv_home
                      3.6T   17G  3.4T   1% /home
```

Now its fine but when load increase space is full and my sql is damaged.

Comment: FYI, technically speaking you're using the wrong terminology here, which is probably a large part of the reason you got a downvote. The directory itself, under the hood, is a file, so to increase its size you simply add more entries (i.e. files) to it. What you actually want to do is increase the size of the root *filesystem*, or root *partition*. You also probably garnered downvotes because this is a pretty basic question that almost certainly has already been answered, or is at least trivial to figure out by doing basic research. So, someone probably downvoted because of no research.

Answer (score 1):

```
lvextend -L100G vg_host/lv_root
resize2fs /dev/vg_host/lv_root
```

Comment: both command not work

Comment: Your VG probably doesn't have any free extents, given that `lv_home` is so ridiculously big.  If `vgs` shows `VFree` of `0`, that's the problem.  Shrink down `lv_home` to something sensible, then you'll have plenty of space.